# What is the best way to manage locations in sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I am working on job portal where I have to store the location of the candidate in  "CandidateInfo" table. What is the best way to go ahead with this ?

The easy approach I know for this is to populate a city table and allow the users to select one from the drop down and store the CityID in the CandidateInfo table. But if the city that user search for is not available in the DB , then I should give the user an option to manually type in the  city name. Here is where my question arises.

1) Should I add this newly typed city to my city table ? and then refer the ID of the row in the other tables  OR

2) Should I add the newly typed city in separate column of CandidateInfo table ?

How is LinkedIn & Facebook managing this ? I guess Latitude and Longitude is not the best solution for this ?

Comment: Option 1 is better than option 2.  However, you could end up with a large number of cities, so take that into account when you design your data entry form.  Also, city might not be the best name for your table, since people also live in towns and villages.

Comment: Use the allcountries.zip file from geonames.org to pre-populate your database. it has a lot of cities!

Answer (score 1):

The approach I've taken in the past for large lists like city, county, occupation is to have a company approved master list complete with phonetic codes to allow for misspellings.

I've also had a thesaurus collection as UK counties in particular have different representations i.e. Shropshire, Salop, Shrops.

The thesaurus will contain all the entries that the master list contains plus the alternative terms.

In most cases a thesaurus and phonetic code is adequate.

In cases where the customer is adamant that they want to add a particular representation of a county then the user interface allows them to do so but the background data store has an explicit data store to capture the missed terms.  This allows two things to happen
1.  A business decision to be taken as to how such occurrence should be handled.  Typically add the new term to the thesaurus data set.
2.  Allow data to be cleansed and conformed retrospectively.

Drop down entry works off the master list.  Free format entry works against the thesaurus and maps the thesaurus terms and thus back to the master list.  It is the Thesaurus ID value that gets recorded in the customer data set.

This means that downstream data consumers get a nice clean data set while also getting full view of the customer behaviour that is entering something different.

This is probably a bit more involved than what you were hoping but I have found it to support both what the customer wants and give the business users useful information.